# How can I get new filtered values in a datatable primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

I  could not find a way to make update of a component after getting filtered values of datatable. I try different ways :

- Test 1 : I try to use the action of the `Filter` event, but this event is done before the change of values, so I can't make my calculation with the new values
- Test 2 : I try to use the Listener of the `Filter` event, but I couldn't find the new values in the `AjaxBehaviorEvent`
- Test 3 : I try to call my function in the setter of the filtered values, the calculation is done but not updated... So I try to use `RequestContext` of primefaces but it doesn't work either.

Tell me if you have an idea to unlock one way, or to propose new solutions =)

Thanks for your help!

Console return, to show the order of the event.

```
>test 1
>test 2
>update other
>update filtered values
>test 3
```

HTML code :

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:dataTable var="_remontee" value="#{ConsultationSaisieBean.m_valuesInDataGrid}" 
    filteredValue="#{ConsultationSaisieBean.m_filteredValues}"  >

        <p:ajax event="filter"  listener="#{ConsultationSaisieBean.OnFilter}" 
        action="#{ConsultationSaisieBean.FilterAction}" update=":form2"/>

        <p:columns value="#{ConsultationSaisieBean.m_columns}" var="column" 
        filterBy="#{_remontee[column.property]}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{_remontee[column.property]}" />
        </p:columns>
   </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
   <p:outputLabel id="other" value="#{ConsultationSaisieBean.m_serviceResult}" />
</h:form>
```

Java class :

```
/**
 * function of the filter event's action
 */
public void FilterAction()
{
    // TEST 1
    System.out.println("test 1");
    setM_consummableResult(Resultof(m_filteredValues))
}

/**
 * function of event's listener 
 */
public Map<String, Object>  OnFilter(AjaxBehaviorEvent p_event)
{
    // TEST 2
    System.out.println("test 2");
    setM_consummableResult(Resultof(m_filteredValues))

    // return values wanted by the event
    DataTable table = (DataTable) p_event.getSource();
    Map<String, Object> filters = table.getFilters();
    return filters;
}

/**
 * Setter of the filtered values
 */
public void setM_filteredValues(List<Map<String, String>> p_filteredValues)
{
    // UPDATE FILTERED VALUES
    System.out.println("update filtered values");

    super.setM_filteredValues(p_filteredValues);

    // TEST 3
    System.out.println("test 3");
    setM_consummableResult(Resultof(m_filteredValues))

    //Test to force update 
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addCallbackParam("saved", true); 
    context.update("form2:other");
}

/**
 * function to count the new result
 */
public void Resultof(List<Map<String, String>> p_filteredValues)
{
    /* calcul the new values */
}

/**
 * getter for update the other component
 */
public Double getM_consummableResult()
{
    return m_consummableResult;
    // UPDATE
    System.out.println("update other");
}

public List<Map<String, String>> getM_filteredValues()
{
    return m_filteredValues;
}

private void setM_consummableResult(Double m_consummableResult)
{
    this.m_consummableResult = m_consummableResult;
}
```

Comment: use a LazyDataModel, much easier

Comment: LazyDataModel change the way to get/save the values not the component's events, how can it help me here for the filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem as you. I have solved using remotecommand...

```
 <p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="handleLoadStart();" update=":frm1:tablaFact :frm1:panelTotal"/>
```

...

```
 <p:remoteCommand id="rcom" name="loadRemoteContent" process="@this" update="panelTotal, tablaFact"  actionListener="#{listadoFacturasMB.filterListener2}"/>
```

...

```
  <h:outputScript id="waypointScript" target="body">  
     function handleLoadStart() {                     
                loadRemoteContent();                       
                }

 </h:outputScript>
```

...

```
 public void filterListener2() {
    try {
        if (filterFacturaUtilList != null) {
          //then filter is active, do something...
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: filterListener() " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

filterFacturaUtilList is a filteredValue